# Window functions to count distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The query below is based on a complicated view and the view works as I want it to (I'm not going to include the view because I don't think it will help with the question at hand).  What I can't get right is the `drugCountsinFamilies` column.  I need it to show me the number of `distinct drugName`s for each drug family.  You can see from the first screencap that there are three different H3A rows.  The `drugCountsInFamilies` for H3A should be 3 (there are three different  H3A drugs.  )

[image]

You can see from the second screen cap that what's happening is the `drugCountsInFamilies` in the first screen cap is catching the number of rows that the drug name is listed on.
[image]

Below is my question, with comments on the part that is incorrect

```
select distinct
     rx.patid
    ,d2.fillDate
    ,d2.scriptEndDate
    ,rx.drugName
    ,rx.drugClass
    --the line directly below is the one that I can't figure out why it's wrong
    ,COUNT(rx.drugClass) over(partition by rx.patid,rx.drugclass,rx.drugname) as drugCountsInFamilies
from 
(
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by d.patid order by d.patid,d.uniquedrugsintimeframe desc) as rn
    ,d.patid
    ,d.fillDate
    ,d.scriptEndDate
    ,d.uniqueDrugsInTimeFrame
    from DrugsPerTimeFrame as d
)d2
inner join rx on rx.patid = d2.patid
inner join DrugTable as dt on dt.drugClass=rx.drugClass
where d2.rn=1 and rx.fillDate between d2.fillDate and d2.scriptEndDate
and dt.drugClass in ('h3a','h6h','h4b','h2f','h2s','j7c','h2e')
order by rx.patid
```

SSMS gets mad if I try to add a distinct to the `count(rx.drugClass)` clause.  Can it be done using window functions?

Comment: @ littlebobbytables I can't use `count(distinct rx.drugClass) over(partition by...)` without getting an error.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables that won't work because I need two `different` drugs in the same class.  If the same drugName is listed twice, it's also in the same class, but I need to count it once.

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense, because you have rx.drugClass in the partitioning clause.  Hence, `count(distinct rx.drugClass)` will always return 1.

Comment: I didn't think that was right, but I tried everything under the sun partitioning wise to make it give me the correct answer.  I'll probably end up just using a derived table, but I was hoping I could figure it out this way.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Doing a `count(distinct)` as a windows function requires a trick.  Several levels of tricks, actually.

Because your request is actually truly simple -- the value is always 1 because rx.drugClass is in the partitioning clause -- I will make an assumption.  Let's say you want to count the number of unique drug classes per patid.

If so, do a `row_number()` partitioned by patid and drugClass.  When this is 1, within a patid, , then a new drugClass is starting.  Create a flag that is 1 in this case and 0 in all other cases.

Then, you can simply do a `sum` with a partitioning clause to get the number of distinct values.

The query (after formatting it so I can read it), looks like:

```
select rx.patid, d2.fillDate, d2.scriptEndDate, rx.drugName, rx.drugClass,
       SUM(IsFirstRowInGroup) over (partition by rx.patid) as NumDrugCount
from (select distinct rx.patid, d2.fillDate, d2.scriptEndDate, rx.drugName, rx.drugClass,
             (case when 1 = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by rx.drugClass, rx.patid order by (select NULL))
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as IsFirstRowInGroup
      from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by d.patid order by d.patid,d.uniquedrugsintimeframe desc) as rn, 
                   d.patid, d.fillDate, d.scriptEndDate, d.uniqueDrugsInTimeFrame
            from DrugsPerTimeFrame as d
           ) d2 inner join
           rx
           on rx.patid = d2.patid inner join
           DrugTable dt
           on dt.drugClass = rx.drugClass
      where d2.rn=1 and rx.fillDate between d2.fillDate and d2.scriptEndDate and
            dt.drugClass in ('h3a','h6h','h4b','h2f','h2s','j7c','h2e')
     ) t
order by patid
```

Comment: You know a good resource for the logic behind formatting SQL?  Because what I find readable and what SQL Server and others on SO say are two very different things. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie . . . My style is rather personally developed over the years (decades) I've been working with SQL.  I think I describe it in Chapter 1 of "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  I find that when I try to adjust to radically dissimilar formats, I tend to miss important elements of the langauge.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The `case when 1 = ROW_NUMBER()...` for a later summation in the next in-line view was a wonderful grand master move.

Comment: @DougPorter . . . Please do not do me the "favor" of reformatting my code.  You can read about my indentation style in Chapter 1 of "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  It is quite intentional.

Answer (score 67):

I came across this question in search for a solution to my problem of counting distinct values. In searching for an answer I came across this [post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1455129-391-1.aspx). See last comment. I've tested it and used the SQL. It works really well for me and I figured that I would provide another solution here.

In summary, using `DENSE_RANK()`, with `PARTITION BY` the grouped columns, and `ORDER BY` both `ASC` and `DESC` on the columns to count:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY drugClass ORDER BY drugName ASC) +
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY drugClass ORDER BY drugName DESC) - 1 AS drugCountsInFamilies
```

I use this as a template for myself.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PartitionByFields ORDER BY OrderByFields ASC ) +
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PartitionByFields ORDER BY OrderByFields DESC) - 1 AS DistinctCount
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @tibtib I would suggest writing out your full response so that your goal is clear.

Comment: My prior comment was not correct, so I deleted it. On a basic level, I was just noticing that the MAX of a DENSE_RANK can give the same result in a slightly more intuitive way. You would just have to wrap an aggregating MAX in a window function for correct partitioning. So, something like: `SELECT class, name, MAX(MAX(dense_rank)) OVER (PARTITION BY class) FROM (SELECT class, name, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY class ORDER BY name)) AS ex_table GROUP BY 1, 2`

Comment: -1 WRONG: Suppose you have three columns: time, animalId, cameraId. I want to select distinct number of cameras for each animal. This will give you 1 for all results.

Comment: if I `PARTITION BY animalId, cameraId`. Otherwise, if partitioning by a single column, will partition against all window instead of against each animal

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow Are you replying to my answer or to a comment on my answer?

Comment: @JoeFletch I am commenting towards the answer itself.

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow thanks for your reply. Your initial comment `Suppose you have three columns: time, animalId, cameraId. I want to select distinct number of cameras for each animal. This will give you 1 for all results.`, yes I agree that using my answer with all 3 columns will give you 1 for everything since `time` is probably different for each combination of `animalId` and `cameraId`. I believe that the proper way would be to partition on `animalId` and  sort on `cameraId` (it's tough to say without seeing the data). You second comment above is not clear it may not be complete.

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow so why the downvote and "WRONG" comment? I think that I am missing your point.

Comment: @JoeFletch Ok sorry for that, I can't remove downvote because it requires an edit to be made first

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow sure you can. If you want to upvote, then click the up arrow. If you want to remove your downvote, then press the down arrow again. I just did it on another answer.

Comment: Sorry, tried to upvote, or downvote again still gives me error (can't vote until edited)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181554/discussion-between-joefletch-and-findoutislamnow).

Comment: @wootscootinboogie you should be able to mark this one as the accepted correct answer. Much easier than the originally marked one.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you were trying to do is this as a window function:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT rx.drugName) over(partition by rx.patid,rx.drugclass) as drugCountsInFamilies
```

which SQL complains about.  But you can do this instead:

```
SELECT 
rx.patid
, rx.drugName
, rx.drugClass
, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT rx2.drugName) FROM rx rx2 WHERE rx2.drugClass = rx.DrugClass AND rx2.patid = rx.patid) As drugCountsInFamilies
FROM rx
...
```

If the table is large then it's best to put an index on one of the columns (e.g. patid) so that the nested query doesn't consume a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    MAX(
            dense_rank() 
            OVER (
              ORDER BY name DESC
              PARTITION BY family
            )
          ) 
OVER (
  PARTITION BY family
)
```

Could this work?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [T-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL), it is directly possible to use a window function by using `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT`, so for example:

```
    APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(rx.drugClass) OVER(PARTITION BY rx.patid, rx.drugclass, rx.drugname) AS drugCountsInFamilies
```

You can find more information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/approx-count-distinct-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score -5):

Why would something like this not work?

```
SELECT 
   IDCol_1
  ,IDCol_2
  ,Count(*) Over(Partition By IDCol_1, IDCol_2 order by IDCol_1) as numDistinct
FROM Table_1
```

Comment: What does it contribute to the answers of 2012? NB: `order by` makes no sense in a window for `count`.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?