# SQL Count Distinct with multiple condition, to return all columns, all records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good Day, I'm trying to count the number of distinct values given a condition but, I need the query result to include all columns, and records. Basically, the distinct count result will be added as a new column to the original table and will just be repeated for each row.

This is what I have so far and I can't get to the next step. I have three tables joined together.  I want to count the unique T.CostCenter in tbl_trantype, given that R.ID (from tbl_reqtype) and R.DocumentNo (from tbl_reqtype) is the same.

```
SELECT M.[ID] AS EMLID
        ,R.[ID] AS RequestID
        ,T.[ID] AS TransactionID
        ,R.[DocumentNo]
        ,T.[CostCenter]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.ID, R.DocumentNo, T.CostCenter ORDER BY T.ID) NoOfCostCenter 
FROM (tbl_Info M
        INNER JOIN tbl_reqtype R ON M.ID = R.EMLID)
        INNER JOIN tbl_trantype T ON R.ID = T.RID
```

Below is the result I'm hoping

```
EMLID   RequestID   TransactionID   DocumentNo  CostCenter  NoOfCostCenter
4000001    11           1           777777777   1515151         2
4000001    11           2           777777777   1515151         2
4000001    11           3           777777777   4515151         2
4000003    12           4           999999999   7277477         5
4000003    12           5           999999999   7277477         5
4000003    12           6           999999999   8722724         5
4000003    12           7           999999999   7272726         5
4000003    12           8           999999999   2652627         5
4000003    12           9           999999999   6353636         5
```

Comment: Your question would benefit from not only showing the expected result, but also the input, which would give the result (e.g. the contents of the queried tables). You could also try simplifying it by removing the joins from the question (show a simple table with just the columns relevant to the question).

Comment: @Hilarion, Apologies I will take that in mind when I post next time. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It seems, that you are close. I'd go with this query:</strike>

```
SELECT M.[ID] AS EMLID
        ,R.[ID] AS RequestID
        ,T.[ID] AS TransactionID
        ,R.[DocumentNo]
        ,T.[CostCenter]
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT T.CostCenter) OVER (PARTITION BY R.ID, R.DocumentNo) NoOfCostCenter 
FROM (tbl_Info M
        INNER JOIN tbl_reqtype R ON M.ID = R.EMLID)
        INNER JOIN tbl_trantype T ON R.ID = T.RID
```

I've simply replaced the `ROW_NUMBER` with a `COUNT` (and removed `ORDER BY`, which is irrelevant for counting, and removed what we're counting, from the partitioning).

But I can't be sure, as you've given no specifics on the input.

**Edit**: I'm sorry, I've forgotten that this is T-SQL, not Oracle DB SQL, so the `DISTINCT` clause will not work.
You'll probably find this answer helpful: [Window functions to count distinct records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480880)

One of the solutions/answers from that questions would apply like this:

```
SELECT M.[ID] AS EMLID
        ,R.[ID] AS RequestID
        ,T.[ID] AS TransactionID
        ,R.[DocumentNo]
        ,T.[CostCenter]
        ,DENSE_RANK()
           OVER (PARTITION BY R.[ID], R.[DocumentNo] ORDER BY T.[CostCenter])
         + DENSE_RANK()
           OVER (PARTITION BY R.[ID], R.[DocumentNo] ORDER BY T.[CostCenter] DESC)
         - 1 as [NoOfCostCenter]
  FROM (tbl_Info M
        INNER JOIN tbl_reqtype R ON M.ID = R.EMLID)
        INNER JOIN tbl_trantype T ON R.ID = T.RID
 ORDER BY [TransactionID]
```

This [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=54ed5a704a36fc4a3a26b3684f498134) shows the result (with a bit simplified source / input structure).

Comment: Oh My! Thank you so much @Hilarion... I'm so happy! I truly appreciate this. Thank you Thank you! You've helped me a lot!