# SQL Query to determine number of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have this table and I'm trying to determine how many Tables (in a restaurant) are awaiting food.
The table( in the database) has the following columns:
TableNumber, ObjectType, ObjectDescription and Quantity (amongst others).

I made this query to see what is ordered, but would like to know how many unique tables are waiting for food.....

```
SELECT TableNumber AS TAFEL
    , COUNT (*) AS AANTAL
    , ObjectDescription AS PRODUCT
FROM TableMemory 
WHERE (ObjectType = 1 OR ObjectType = 17)
GROUP BY TableNumber, ObjectType, ObjectDescription
ORDER BY TableNumber
```

which gives me the following output...

```
TAFEL       AANTAL      PRODUCT             ### OF TABLES
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           1           Black Jacks Hotdog         5                       
1           5           Friet Groot                                       
1           2           Friet Klein                                       
1           1           Friet Middel                                     
1           1           Knoflooksaus                                    
1           1           Uitsmijter Ham/kaas                              
1           1           Uitsmijter Lou                                   
3           1           Knoflooksaus                                      
3           1           New York Hotdog                                   
7           1           Broodje Gezond                                    
7           1           Knoflooksaus                                      
40          1           Friet Groot                                       
40          1           Met Uitjes                                        
60          1           Friet Middel                                      
60          1           Meenemen
```

I tried to use count and distinct in the query but nothing I tried seems to give me an extra output for the unique number of tables(restaurant) which should be 5 in the above result.

Can anyone help me? Grateful in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample data and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Are you trying to add the number of distinct tables to this query? Or as a separate query? Either way please show your desired results.

Comment: @Dale K I would like to get another column in the grid which represents the number of tables i.e. ### OF TABLES... The query is only used to represent; not to ad anything in the DBTABLE.

Comment: As I said, please show your desired results so its clear.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff The database I'm using is MSSQL Server 2005. How do I provide sample data? Sorry, kind of new to this stuff.

Comment: @Dale The grid should become this...

Comment: Also need to see some raw sample data. Ideally as DDL+DML.

Comment: @Dale The grid should become like the above output with an extra column showing the total unique tables. In this case 5. Can't seem to paste it here....

Comment: As I said [edit] it into your question to create a [MRE]

Comment: You only want to show the value of the number of tables on the first row?

Comment: @DaleK All rows would be OK too

Comment: @DaleK ### OF TABLES is the number of Restaurant "TAFELS" people eat from; not the DBTables. BTW Thanks for helping!

Comment: If you don't know or cannot communicate what your resultset should be, then you and everyone else will struggle. Currently your resultset contains one row for each food (objectdescription) per table (tafel). Yet you ask about how many tables awaiting food - which is a single, scalar value. Mixing the terminology between languages and column names (vs. alias) adds to the confusion. In the end, you want that last column to represent the count of all tables awaiting any food and that value is the same for every row. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a column which contains the (repeated) [### OF TABLES] you could use CROSS JOIN

```
/* This will repeat the [### OF TABLES] for each row of the results */
;with
prod_cte as (
    SELECT TableNumber AS TAFEL
        , COUNT (*) AS AANTAL
        , ObjectDescription AS PRODUCT
    FROM TableMemory 
    WHERE (ObjectType = 1 OR ObjectType = 17)
    GROUP BY TableNumber, ObjectType, ObjectDescription),
total_cte as (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TableNumber) [### OF TABLES]
    FROM TableMemory 
    WHERE ObjectType IN (1, 17)) 
select p.*, t.*
from prod_cte p
     cross join total_cte t;
```

[Edit] Without the CTE to work in SQL 2000

```
select p.*, t.*
from (
    SELECT TableNumber AS TAFEL
        , COUNT (*) AS AANTAL
        , ObjectDescription AS PRODUCT
    FROM TableMemory 
    WHERE (ObjectType = 1 OR ObjectType = 17)
    GROUP BY TableNumber, ObjectType, ObjectDescription) p,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TableNumber) [### OF TABLES]
    FROM TableMemory 
    WHERE ObjectType IN (1, 17)) t;
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your help! Pasted the code in VS2019 and got this... `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.`

Comment: It's updated now.  I deleted the ORDER BY clause in the upper CTE

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Line 8: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Aaaah, just checked: DB is SQLServer2000. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @OldJan um yes, SQL Server 2000 has been out of support for a version long time now... why are you still using it?

Comment: The downside of this approach is having to repeat your `where` clause in 2 places. Also a rough performance check shows this being slower.

Comment: @DaleK I tried to upgrade the DB to 2008R2 but the application that uses it will not connect to it. I can restore the DB but when I start the application (old POS system made in Borland C++) it will not connect. Too old I assume....

Comment: It should work even on SQL 2k, not sure what's wrong.  Sample data would help.  @DaleK this query should return the correct answer.  Afaik the distinct TableNumber values to be counted are { 1, 3, 7, 40, 60 }

Comment: @SteveC CTE's were introduced in 2005, not 2000. It does return the correct results, but requires a duplicated `where` clause, and is slower.

Comment: Please review, the code was updated to work in SQL 2k.  @DaleK your code also contains a duplicated where clause

Comment: @SteveC it does now :) but I made that comment back when cte's and window functions were available lol. Thats all out the window for SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Not sure window functions are needed in this case.  As @DaleK pointed out SQL 2000 is ancient and not supported.  And don't update to 2008R2 that's ancient and unsupported too

Comment: @SteveC the purpose of the window function was to avoid repeating the `where` clause - i.e. remove the risk of changing one and not the other. That is why I would prefer that option if its available. And aside from that its faster anyway. Of course thats all irrelevant on SQL Server 2000 - but good practice on supported versions.

Comment: @SteveC Hi Steve, you are the best!!!!!!!!! It works! Thank you so much! And of course Dale and others too for your tine and effort!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly its very important to tell us if you are using a vintage version of SQL Server. A lot has changed since 2000!

Secondly, really you are going about obtaining your data the wrong way. You are trying to combine 2 sets of data which aren't related. The correct way to handle this is to pull 2 datasets, 1 with the number of tables (Gordon has already provided this), and one with the aggregated values per table (which you already have). If for some reason you really can't do this then see the option below using a simple sub-query.

#### SQL Server - Window Functions Not Supported

Use a simple sub-query, being careful to duplicate the `where` clauses.

```
SELECT TableNumber AS TAFEL
    , COUNT (*) AS AANTAL
    , ObjectDescription AS PRODUCT
    , (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TableNumber) 
      FROM TableMemory 
      WHERE ObjectType IN (1, 17)
    ) TableCount
FROM TableMemory 
WHERE ObjectType IN (1, 17)
GROUP BY TableNumber, ObjectType, ObjectDescription
ORDER BY TableNumber;
```

#### SQL Server - Window Functions Supported

With reference to Gordon's [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480880/window-functions-to-count-distinct-records/13481415#13481415) to a similar question (which I admit could be hard to translate, hence why I haven't flagged as a duplicate), you can do it as follows.

1. Compute a row number partitioned by `TableNumber`.
2. Count how many rows with row number = 1 there are. Because row number 1 will only exist once per `TableNumber`. Note I do this in a `CROSS APPLY` to avoid duplicating the logic twice, once in the `SELECT` and once in the `GROUP BY`.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT TableNumber AS TAFEL
      , ObjectDescription AS PRODUCT
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableNumber ORDER BY ObjectDescription) rn
  FROM TableMemory T
  WHERE ObjectType IN (1, 17)
)
SELECT TAFEL, PRODUCT
    , COUNT (*) AS AANTAL
    , SUM(RowToCount) OVER () TableCount
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS X (RowToCount)
GROUP BY TAFEL, PRODUCT, RowToCount
ORDER BY TAFEL;
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! I pasted your code in VS2019 and got the following errors... `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER' `

Comment: @OldJan . . . Your question is tagged SQL Server.  All supported versions support both CTEs (`with`) and `row_number()`.  In fact, most unsupported versions do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "tafel" is table, then just use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TableNumber) 
FROM TableMemory 
WHERE ObjectType IN (1, 17);
```

If you want your original data with the number of distinct tables, then just add `dense_rank()` twice:

```
SELECT TableNumber AS TAFEL, COUNT (*) AS AANTAL,
       ObjectDescription AS PRODUCT,
       (-1 +
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TableNumber ASC) +
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TableNumber DESC)
       ) as num_tables
FROM TableMemory 
WHERE (ObjectType = 1 OR ObjectType = 17)
GROUP BY TableNumber, ObjectType, ObjectDescription
ORDER BY TableNumber;
```

Comment: The "Tafel" is the restaurant table people eat from..... The query in my question shoud be extended to determine the number of unique restaurant tables.... A bit confusing huh? BtW thanks answering!

Comment: It doesn't work either..... Thanks for your time! I'm going to bed now; It's almost three in the night here......

Comment: Interestingly, while neater that seems to be slower (as a rough cehck) than my row_number solution.

Comment: @DaleK . . . That is interesting, actually.