# RANK or ROWNUM or different?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find orders with multiple products and exclude orders with only one product.

My data is organized as follows:

| ORDER_ID | PRODUCT_GROUP_ID | PRODUCT_ID | PROD_RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3574 | 1038 | 460 | 1 |
| 3574 | 1038 | 461 | 2 |
| 3574 | 1038 | 462 | 3 |
| 3574 | 3748 | 750 | 1 |
| 1417 | 9113 | 175 | 1 |
| 2265 | 8202 | 472 | 1 |
| 2265 | 3203 | 475 | 1 |

I've tested trying to grab only order with multiple product by this basic rank SQL and it does what it should, but how do I exclude order id 1417 from the rank? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Below is the SQL with the output. As you can see, the rank is doing it's job but now I need to exclude all orders with only one product_group_id (1417).

Thanks

```
WITH TESTRANK AS(
        SELECT
                ORDER_ID
                ,PRODUCT_GROUP_ID
                ,PRODUCT_ID
                ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_GROUP_ID ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID) AS ROWNUM_RANK
 
        FROM ORDER_DETAIL
        WHERE
                ORDER_ID IN (3574, 1417, 2265)
        )
SELECT * FROM TESTRANK
--WHERE ROWNUM_RANK=1
```

| ORDER_ID | PRODUCT_GROUP_ID | PRODUCT_ID | PROD_RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3574 | 1038 | 460 | 1 |
| 3574 | 3748 | 750 | 1 |
| 1417 | 9113 | 175 | 1 |
| 2265 | 8202 | 472 | 1 |
| 2265 | 3203 | 475 | 1 |

Comment: `group by order_id having count(distinct product_id) > 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_GROUP_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID)` which unfortunately isn't possible. But which can be mimicked using [`DENSE_RANK`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44420298/1127428).

```
WITH TESTRANK AS (
    SELECT
        ORDER_ID
        , PRODUCT_GROUP_ID
        , PRODUCT_ID
        , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_GROUP_ID ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID) AS ROWNUM_RANK

        -- Count distinct window function
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID ORDER BY PRODUCT_GROUP_ID ASC) +
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID ORDER BY PRODUCT_GROUP_ID DESC) - 1 AS WINDOW_COUNT
    FROM #ORDER_DETAIL
    WHERE ORDER_ID IN (3574, 1417, 2265)
)
SELECT *
FROM TESTRANK
WHERE ROWNUM_RANK = 1 and WINDOW_COUNT > 1;
```

Returns:

| ORDER_ID | PRODUCT_GROUP_ID | PRODUCT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2265 | 8202 | 472 |
| 2265 | 3203 | 475 |
| 3574 | 3748 | 750 |
| 3574 | 1038 | 460 |

Comment: Thank you that works! Now I have another question. Now I'm trying to get the max row_number of products for each order_id, but I only want the max row_number printed on the max row and all others should be 0. Example: row 2265 8202 472 would have column CT =0; row 2265 3203 475 column CT would be 2. I tried a max(row_number) in a case statement in the query above but of course that doesn't work. Do I need to join the table back on itself to do a count or do a row_number on the result set? Thanks!!

Comment: Firstly that is really a front end job... you shouldn't be trying to make your data pretty in the database. Secondly should you wish to do so ask a new question.

Comment: Hi Dale, thank you. I thought I had accepted your answer. I will also ask a new question with more context.

Comment: Hi Dale- I think we're all good with accepting? Thanks again, this board is a great resource!!

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `max()` and `min()`:

```
WITH TESTRANK AS (
        SELECT ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_GROUP_ID, PRODUCT_ID,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_GROUP_ID ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID) AS ROWNUM_RANK,
               MAX(PRODUCT_GROUP_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID) as MAX_PGI,
               MIN(PRODUCT_GROUP_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID) as MIN_PGI,
        FROM ORDER_DETAIL OD
        WHERE ORDER_ID IN (3574, 1417, 2265)
       )
SELECT *
FROM TESTRANK
WHERE MIN_PGI <> MAX_PGI;
```